# How can i get more inliers when using ransac?

Tags: python, matching, homography, ransac

```
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x: x.distance)
src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
```

I'm using the value in matchesMask as the inliers which is proving to be too severely affected by ransac, i tried to get only the first 100 best matches out of matches but the % of outliers was still too high.

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.findHomography`  treat a point pair as an inlier if the distance between the source point and the projection of the destination is grater than `ransacReprojThreshold` (5.0 - in your code):

```
norm(src_pts[i] - M * dst_pts[i]) > ransacReprojThreshold
```

[ransacReprojThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) - Maximum allowed reprojection error to treat a point pair as an inlier.

So, If you want to find 100 "best" matches, even if it's reprojection error more than 5.0:

1. create an array of pairs: (point pair and reprojection error),
2. sort by reprojection error,
3. take 100 points with smallest reprojection error.